# mail() sends the message as .txt file

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to PHP so don't mind the `@`... was a quick fix for opening the script without errors

I'm currently working on a mail script and its working pretty well.
Sadly it sends the text the user enters as a `.txt` file instead of plain text

Basically the form is stored in `messenger_mailsend.php` and the content of the Textarea gets to `messenger_mailsend_controller.php` by using `$_POST[]`.

```
    @$inhalt = $_POST['inhalt'];
    $message = strip_tags($inhalt);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    @mail($mailto, $subject, 'why not zoidberg?', $headers); 
    echo 'The mail was sent!';
    }
```

'why not zoidberg' is the test text i used to check if theres sth wrong with the var, actually it says `mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);`

is the code I use to get the typed message from the form, remove the tags and store it as `$message`.

If I do a `var_dump` it says 'I am content' (what was typed in the form).. 
when the `$message` var is replaced by some plain text it still gets sent as `TEXT.txt`

The code i use for the $headers is:

```
    $headers .= 'From:' . $usrmail . "\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To:' . $reply . "\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\n";
$headers .= 'X-Sender-IP:' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';

$headers .= 'Cc: ' . $cc . "\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . $bcc . "\n";
```

-- Solution: By setting the content-type to text/plain it works, thanks anyone! --

Comment: please post the call of the mail function

Comment: Why are you properly checking if `$_POST['inhalt']` is set? using `@` is **BAD** and lazy.

Comment: What have you put in $mailto, $subject and $headers?

Comment: replace 'why not zoidberg' with $message. and post the complete code ...

Answer (score 0):

Well how can you expect the mail to be sent as html when you are stripping all the html tags before sending....

However, if you want to send the html mail, you have to define the same in the headers before sending. See the snippet:

```
$to = 'bob@example.com';
$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

@$inhalt = $_POST['inhalt'];
$message = strip_tags($inhalt);
```

And then you send the mail like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: theres no difference if i dont remove the tags :/ without removing them, the content of the file is "<p>Im content</p>", with removing its just "Im content"

Comment: fine, then its just that you have to attach the $header variable as mentioned in the code snippet above, before doing the mail()......You need to define the content-type before sending the mail. Remember, default is jst plain txt format.